# Convert External format to Internal format

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, converters

I need a solution for this problem:

I'm a service provider and there are several service clients who I work with.
each service client sends me request by its own format, for instance:

```
service client 1 fields are --> f1 , f2 , f3
service client 2 fields are --> f2 , f3 , f4
service client 3 fields are --> f3 , f7 , f8
```

it is possible they add or remove new fields or change their current format, for example "service client 1" combines:

```
 f1+f2 ==> f12 and adds f5
```

or client 3 :

```
 decomposes f7 ---> f1,f2
```

I need an internal format for myself, for instance :

```
  f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9
```

this format should be configurable in a way that I can change it by xml configuration file so when a change happens on client side I fix it by changing xml without changing source code.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, you need an API to which hand over your external message plus a “how to” file and it does some magic on it and deliver you the internal message. Let’s focus on the main duty of the API which is message conversion. As you mentioned it should be configurable by an XML config file. We need an element that can be called “Field” which has at least one attribute which I call “name”. I wrap a collection of these Field elements within a parent element. Every one of “Field” elements designates a field in the target internal message. Within the Field element I like to add another element which is responsible to gather my desired fields and does a function on them. Here’s a sample of an XML config:

```
<fields>
    <field name="aLong">
        <function name="add">
            <arg>
                <function name="readExternalField">
                    <arg>
                        f1
                    </arg>
                </function>
            </arg>
            <arg>
                <function name="readExternalField">
                    <arg>
                        f2
                    </arg>
                </function>
            </arg>
        </function>
    </field>
    <field name="aStr">
        <function name="getFromArray" index="0">
            <arg>
                <function name="splitStr" character=" ">
                    <arg>
                        <function name="readExternalField">
                            <arg>
                                f3
                            </arg>
                        </function>
                    </arg>
                </function>
            <arg>
        </function>
    </field>
</fields>
```

Imagine we have an internal object which has at least two fields called “aLong” and “aStr” and an external object which has at least three fields: “f1”, “f2”and “f3”. The point is I must make sure of using the functions that their return types are assignable to the target fields. The function “add” adds the value of fields “f1” and “f2” and the result must be assigned to the field “aLong” and the function “splitStr” splits the “f3” field and returns an array which the function “getFromArray” gets the first item of the array as the result.
 I prefer to use the JAXB API to unmarshal my XML file and to parse it easily, so we need an XSD document which can be generated from the XML file through the online tools. I suggest to utilize map based objects to eliminate the need of doing the reflection stuff. If you develop REST services, the received JSON message can be converted to a map object. In this way your API has a method which receives a map based object and returns the same. So, every field is a key in the map not a field in a class. But the functions can have certain parameters with specific types. The main body of the API must cast the got objects from the external map before passing them to the functions and put the returned value to the internal message with the specified field name in the XML file.
I hope this brief answer illuminates the way to a satisfactory solution and remember that writing an efficient API which you can share with your colleagues proudly is a skill and only practice gives it to you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share all of that great information with me. your solution is quite comprehensive and is entirely what I needed.